# Override element name from within element object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to create an object model to be able to output the following XML using JAXB:

```
<root version="1">
    <first version="1"/>
</root>
```

Or this:

```
<root version="1">
    <second version="1"/>
</root>
```

Obviously an oversimplified version for this example. There can only be either a sub element of type `first` or `second`, not both at once.

My root element looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class ExampleRootElement {
    private int version;
    private ExampleBaseSubElement subElement;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "version")
    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public ExampleBaseSubElement getSubElement() {
        return subElement;
    }

    public void setSubElement(ExampleBaseSubElement subElement) {
        this.subElement = subElement;
    }
}
```

Since the child element has to be either `first` or `second` I created an empty abstract dummy class `ExampleBaseSubElement` to extend from in the specific classes for `first` and `second`. I would have used an interface here, but apparently JAXB isn't able to handle these. (I usually did this kind of stuff in C#, so excuse me if this is a really bad way to do it in Java using JAXB)

The dummy class:

```
public abstract class ExampleBaseSubElement {
}
```

Code for `first`:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="first")
public class ExampleFirstSubElement extends ExampleBaseSubElement {
    private int version;

    @XmlAttribute(name="version")
    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

Code for `second`: (Just for the sake of this sample pretty much the same as `first`)

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "second")
public class ExampleSecondSubElement extends ExampleBaseSubElement {
    private int version;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "version")
    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

What is probably wrong is my expectation about setting the element name from within the class using the `XmlRootElement` annotation, because it doesn't work. I've tried to create the desired XML output by creating an `ExampleRootElement` with a nested `ExampleFirstSubElement` like this:

```
ExampleRootElement exampleRootElement = new ExampleRootElement();
exampleRootElement.setVersion(1);
ExampleFirstSubElement exampleFirstSubElement = new ExampleFirstSubElement();
exampleFirstSubElement.setVersion(1);
exampleRootElement.setSubElement(exampleFirstSubElement);

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ExampleRootElement.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

marshaller.marshal(exampleRootElement, System.out);
```

This results in:

```
<root version="1">
    <subElement/>
</root>
```

The expectation was:

```
<root version="1">
    <first version="1"/>
</root>
```

Ok, I get that this doesn't work. The annotation is simply ignored. Probably because JAXB doesn't resolve the extended type, which would explain why the attribute `version` for the nested element is missing, too. And I am pretty positive on the feeling that unmarshalling this will fail even harder ...

So my question is: Am I missing some kind of magic annotation here so this can work as intended or is this the wrong approach altogether, and if so, what's the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after tinkering around with different annotations (basically brute-forcing it) I came up with the following solution:

Adding `XmlSeeAlso` to the abstract base class `ExampleBaseSubElement`:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({
        ExampleFirstSubElement.class,
        ExampleSecondSubElement.class
})
public abstract class ExampleBaseSubElement {
}
```

Adding `XmlElementRef` to the getter of `subElement` within `ExampleRootElement`:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class ExampleRootElement {
    private int version;
    private ExampleBaseSubElement subElement;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "version")
    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @XmlElementRef // here!
    public ExampleBaseSubElement getSubElement() {
        return subElement;
    }

    public void setSubElement(ExampleBaseSubElement subElement) {
        this.subElement = subElement;
    }
}
```

This now results in the expected output:

```
<root version="1">
    <first version="1"/>
</root>
```

I am still not sure if this is bad in general or actually how it's supposed to be done. It works and I hope this helps someone else facing the same problem.

Comment: Hello Num Lock can you take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875849/how-to-utilize-jaxb-for-object-serialization-for-sub-elements-with-same-tag-name/41876211?noredirect=1#comment70978243_41876211